# How do I negate a selector in J lang?

Tags: j

I am playing with selection. Let's look at the initial example:

```
rarg=. 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
   _1 (<(<0 1),(<0 1)) } ( 4 4 $ rarg)
_1 _1  2  3
_1 _1  6  7
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

Here I want to overwrite block {rows=0,1; columns=0,1}. I can use instead of -1 the block :

```
   (2 2 $ _1 _2 _3 _4) (<(<0 1),(<0 1)) } ( 4 4 $ rarg)
_1 _2  2  3
_3 _4  6  7
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

If I negate rows and columns choice in selector I end-up with the expected:

```
   _1 (<(<<0 1),(<<0 1)) } ( 4 4 $ rarg)
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 _1 _1
12 13 _1 _1
```

So far so good. But let's assume I want to "negate" the selector **(<(<0 1),(<0 1))** and have something like this:

```
   _1 NEGATED_SEL } ( 4 4 $ rarg)
0   1  _1  _1
4   5  _1  _1
_1 _1  _1  _1
_1 _1  _1  _1
```

1. Is there a way to achieve that using the above selector?
2. If yes, what if I would like to specify not -1 but arbitrary values?
   Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I believe a number of years ago, `}` was adjusted to reject (signal error on) any non-rectangular selection. So I think this is impossible; I will have to double-check. In the meantime, you can use the monad derived from `}` to *merge* two arrays, thus: `(1 (< (<0 1),(<0 1) )} 4 4 $ 0) } _1 ,: i. 4 4`. Obviously the `_1 ,: … ` can be anything you like, so you can specify arbitrary replacements at the scalar level.

Comment: Ok, confirmed: [`}` started signaling error on non-rectangular selections in J6.01](https://www.jsoftware.com/docs/archive/release/amend.htm) (2006). I’m having a hard time finding the JForum threads that preceded and justified this change, but the net net is you won’t be able to invert the selection the way you want just through clever indexing with dyad `n}` (unless you do the index set calculus yourself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "correct" way would be using `exclude (<)`:

```
(<< 0 1) { i. 4 4
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
(<<< 0 1) { i. 4 4
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

But, as @Dan_Bron mentioned, this is not permitted by `}` as the selection would not be rectangular.

You can still use `exclude` if you first unravel and then re-ravel your input.

```
sel =: <(<<0 1),(<<0 1)
r =: i. 4 4

sel { r
 10 11
 14 15

_1 sel } r
  0  1  2  3
  4  5  6  7
  8  9 _1 _1
 12 13 _1 _1

new =: -i. 12

($r) $ new (<<<,sel { r) } ,r
   0  _1 _2 _3
  _4  _5 _6 _7
  _8  _9 10 11
 _10 _11 14 15
```

For a general input `m`, you could convert the selection to indices by `sel { i. $m`:

```
($m) $ new (<<<,sel { i.$m) } , m
```

Comment: I believe `{` is perfectly happy with non-rectangular selections; it just fills as needed. But `}` doesn’t; before the change I linked to, `}` also allowed arbitrary indices, but where the selection of those indices would have resulted in `{` outputting fill elements, the corresponding amended items were all stuffed at index zero in the ravel (ie the absolute first index) often overwriting each other, seriatim (because where else are you gonna put them? Under the covers J is always dealing with the ravel of the array, and the fill element for indices which are integers is 0).

Comment: This set of circumstances caused confusion, even among veteran Jers, and Roger couldn’t come up a rational and consistent way to treat non-rectangular selections in amend, so he just changed it to reject them. Probably-unnecessarily-detailed history aside, I’m suggest removing *either `{` or* from your sentence *.. not permitted by either `{` or `}` as the ..*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the all comments, hints, code. Below I include what worked for me in the end (with educational decomposing of intermediate steps).

Comment: @DanBron, thanks for the clarifying comments.  RIP Roger.

Comment: @Eelvex Yeah, RIP Roger. That’s a real loss.

Answer (score 2):

A standard way is using a [Composite Item (m})](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/curlyrt) as Dan Bron said:

```
    aNEGATED_SEL1=. 1 : 'y=. (*./~ 1 < i. # y)} y ,: m'  NB. adverb, 1st variant
    aNEGATED_SEL2=. 1 : 'y=. (*:/~ 1 < i. # y)} m ,: y'  NB. adverb, 2nd variant
   _1 aNEGATED_SEL1 ( 4 4 $ rarg)
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 _1 _1
12 13 _1 _1
   _1 aNEGATED_SEL2 ( 4 4 $ rarg)
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 _1 _1
12 13 _1 _1
```

If an overwrite block must vary, it might be supplied as a parameter to a conjunction:

```
   cNEGATED_SEL=. 2 : 'y=. (*./~ n <: i. # y)} y ,: m'
   _1 cNEGATED_SEL 2 ( 4 4 $ rarg)
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 _1 _1
12 13 _1 _1
   _1 cNEGATED_SEL 3 ( 6 6 $ rarg)
 0  1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15  0  1
 2  3  4 _1 _1 _1
 8  9 10 _1 _1 _1
14 15  0 _1 _1 _1
```

The form used above (Noun Modifier) forced to incapsulate an adverb (}). A recent J Engine modifications (since J903 beta-r) may allow a form you requested (Noun Modifier }).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for great hints and answers. The final solution with intermediate steps (for beginner J enthusiasts like myself) to follow

1. Initial matrix

```
   r =: 100 + 5 5 $ i.25
   r
100 101 102 103 104
105 106 107 108 109
110 111 112 113 114
115 116 117 118 119
120 121 122 123 124
```

2. Selection - we want to update everything besides what selects

```
   sel =: <(<1 2),(<1 2)
   sel { r
106 107
111 112
```

3. Indices the selection affects:

```
   ,sel { i.$r
6 7 11 12
```

4. Indices the selection omits:

```
   selIxs =: (< (<< (,sel { i.$r)) ) { ,i.$r
0 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 10 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

5. Final update (we are flattening the matrix to be updated, use vector like updating (here with -1 elements and previously picked ixs) using `}` and finally enforce shape of the initial matrix)

```
   ($r) $ _1 selIxs } ,r
_1  _1  _1 _1 _1
_1 106 107 _1 _1
_1 111 112 _1 _1
_1  _1  _1 _1 _1
_1  _1  _1 _1 _1
```